# Anchor tag not loading value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

Not sure if this is a bug, but I've got the following html code:

```
<a asp-action="CreateUser" asp-controller="Users">
Create new User
</a>
```

But on loading the page the link redirects me to the homepage, on inspecting the element it just shows this

```
<a href="/">
Create new User
</a>
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Using .NET 6

Comment: What's your CreateUser action? Could you share your CreateUser action code ?

Comment: Its just a regular `IActionResult` View, it shouldn't even be relevant should it? Even if the View didn't exist it would normally still load the values into the anchor link

Comment: Do you set a breakpoint at "CreateUser" action ? Can it be excuted ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try,

```
<a href="~/Users/CreateUser">Create new User</a>
```

Or,

```
<a href="@Url.Action("CreateUser","Users")">Create new User</a>
```

Comment: I already switched to one of these, I was just looking for an answer as to why the anchor tags themselves weren't working, but thanks anyway!

Comment: @A-Fairooz sry I never found any of the asp-action equivalent to ever work, and always used either of the above.